# plot two figures in one line in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, figure

I just use the inline in `ipython` to plot figures

```
%matplotlib inline
```

However, since I want to plot thousands of figures in the notebook and compare each two figures at the same time, but `ipython` just give me this [two figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ferp5.png), one is under the other.

I just want to know, how can I put this two pictures in a row. That is one in the right of the other?

And, subplot will not become my choice, because I just use `functions` in a package to plot this two figure.

```
ee.daily_plot(2)
ee.hourly_plot(2)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
z = np.arange(10)**2

nrows = 1
ncols = 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 2)
ax.plot(x, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://tonysyu.github.io/ipython-jupyter-widgets-an-image-convolution-demo.html#.Vz7OlRwqNph).

```
def imshow_pair(image_pair, titles=('', ''), figsize=(10, 5), **kwargs):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=figsize)
    for ax, img, label in zip(axes.ravel(), image_pair, titles):
        ax.imshow(img, **kwargs)
        ax.set_title(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use matplotlib.pyplot.subplot() to plot several subplots in one figure.